# Forecasting with TLSM function from forecast package

Tags: r, lm, forecast

I am foresting with combination of datasets from fpp2 package and tslm function from the forecast package.

```
    # CODE
    library(fpp2) # required for the data
    library(dplyr)
    library(forecast)

    MY_DATA<-uschange[,1:4]
    head(MY_DATA)
    tail(MY_DATA)

    #1 Built own function            
        FORECASTING_FUNCTION_TSLM <- function(Z, hrz = 16) {
        timeseries <- msts(Z, start = 1970, seasonal.periods = 4)
          forecast <- tslm(timeseries~trend+season,biasadj=TRUE)
        }

    #2 Apply own function to whole data set
       FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM<-lapply(MY_DATA, FORECASTING_FUNCTION_TSLM)

    #3 Forecasting 
       TSLM_MODELS_ALL<-lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM,forecast)
```

So here my intention is to get forecasting 16 periods ahead, but last line of above code only give 10 periods of forecasting (last is 2019 Q1). So in order to resolve this code I try with below line of code but I didn't have any result.

```
TSLM_MODELS_ALL<-lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM,forecast(object=FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM,h = 16))
```

So can anybody help me how to fix upper line of code and forecast 16 periods ahead ?

Comment: I think you can just do `TSLM_MODELS_ALL <- lapply(FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM, forecast, h = 16)`

Comment: Thank you.This line work fine